# load a url stored in mysql table using php code along with code igniter frame work, name,url are two columns ,diff user diff url

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
<?php 
//fetched the url from data base and now in controller ,now how to load that url 
$this->load->view('url');
redirect('contoller/viewpagename');
?>
```

1.url returned to controller from model want to load that url in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
<?php 
    $data['url'] = $url; 
    $this->load->view(viewpagename,$data);        
?>
```

url is variable not the string right..?and need not redirect it,when loading the view it will pass the data to the relavent view file,

And in your view file retrieve like

```
<?php echo "This is my URL ".$url;?>
```

**EDIT**
If you want to use stored url as view try to get the controller name and view file names like

```
$my_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $my_path);    
$this->load->view($segments[2],$segments[3]);  // Or u can $url = "'".$segments[2]."/".$segments[3]."'"; and $this->load->view($url);
```

Assuming that 2nd and 3rd segments contains controller name and view file(or function) names respectively..you can change them as per you url

In your comment there is an error..

```
function pagination_student1() { 
     $segment = "student_details"; 
     $url_now = "'".$segment."'"; 
     $this->load->view($this->$url_now,$this->data); 
}
```

replace

```
$this->load->view($this->$url_now,$this->data);
```

with

```
$this->load->view($url_now,$data);
```

Comment: no actually ill store viewpage url in the db table so want to load that using $this->load->view();

Comment: then you need to get the last segment of that url that represents view filename

Comment: function pagination_student1()
 {
  $segment = "student_details";
  $url_now = "'".$segment."'";
         $this->load->view($this->$url_now,$this->data);
 }    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: business::$'student_details'

Filename: controllers/business.php

Line Number: 464

An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: .php

Comment: you just $this->load->view($url_now,$this->data); not $this->$url_now

Comment: ya its working ,thank you for ur help, the actual code goes like this <? function controller_function(){$url_now = "student_details";$this->load->view($url_now); }